# Executing python script in android terminal emulator

Tags: android, python, executable, terminal-emulator

I installed python 2.7 in my Android device and I tried executing a python script by typing the command in terminal emulator. The problem is that although I use the full path for python the following error appears:

`link_image[1997]: failed to link ./python CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE.`

I tried to add environment variables in ./~bashrc but I didn't make it. Any idea ?

Comment: `I tried to add environment variables in ./~bashrc` I think it's a typo, but maybe I'm wrong. It's supposed to be `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake. It is just a typo. You think the error is because of the environment variables?

Comment: No, I don't. I just wanted to make sure it was a typo. I think it's because the way it's compiled/linked. Could you explain how you compiled it in the question?

Comment: path-to-python/python path-to-script/hello.py and i run this command as root with su

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK it is solved. I followed these steps (http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/RunPythonFromShell) but first I had to put the file standalone_python.sh in /data/ because in sdcard I had no permission to execute. And finally using 'su' I made it to run my script as root.